# Filter query results to only those in which the Parent Column's ItemID is not present in the Child column in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have a bill of materials table that shows one column (ManufacturedItemNumber) containing the ItemID of the item produced (which I am calling the parent column, and is enumerated for each sub-item on the BOM), the next column (ItemNumber) displays the ItemID for all of the sub-items that are used in the creation of that parent item as rows.

Children of a BOM can have children of their own.  I am trying to find the highest-level items, items which do not get used in the production of other items.

My query:

This is the filter that does what I want:

```
select  1 as ParentItemFLag,
        bomparent.ManufacturedItemNumber
from    BomLines bomparent
where   not exists (select scr1.* from BomLines scr1 where scr1.ItemNumber = bomparent.ManufacturedItemNumber) and bomparent.ManufacturedItemNumber is not null
```

This the problem area, I want to filter the larger table's results to only those I was able to filter, but the performs is really bad:

```
select  scr2.ParentItemFLag, bom1.BomID, bom1.ManufacturedItemNumber, bom1.ManufacturedItemGroupID, bom1.Quantity
from    bomlines bom1
inner join  (
                select  1 as ParentItemFLag,
                        bomparent.ManufacturedItemNumber
                from    BomLines bomparent
                where   not exists (select scr1.* from BomLines scr1 where scr1.ItemNumber = bomparent.ManufacturedItemNumber) and bomparent.ManufacturedItemNumber is not null
            ) scr2 on scr2.ManufacturedItemNumber = bom1.ManufacturedItemNumber
```

This is the problem spot in the execution plan:
[Execution Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCFIx.png)

I am expecting to filter the entire table by my subquery via an inner join, but for some reason the query is having trouble matching the subquery results to the main query's table.

Comment: `"the next column displays the ItemID for all of the items that were used..."` If you mean this is spread over multiple rows that's fine, but if you have multiple IDs in the same row and column that's a **BROKEN** schema design and you're in for pain. Either way, you should edit the question to clarify the situation.

Comment: I also see this: `"Children of a BOM can have children of their own"`. That usually means you'll want a _Recursive CTE_.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I understand that I eventually need a CTE recursive WITH statement, but I need to have the data in a way that I can use it for Recursion.  There is no column that indicates if an Item is the highest Parent.  That is why I want to do this work around.  In my CTE statement, when I tried WHERE manfuctureditemnumber is null, the results were not was I wanted.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the ManufacturedItemID column reinterates the produced items ItemID for each item that was used to produce it.  That could be once, or as many as 20 times.  Also I don't know how to refrase the question to make the situation more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a CTE instead of a subquery?  I think the subquery you're using now is causing that high cost on the right outer join because it's executing for each row in the outer query.  For the CTE it's only executed once then used in the main query potentially providing better performance

```sql
WITH TopLevelItems AS (
    SELECT 1 AS ParentItemFLag,
           ManufacturedItemNumber
    FROM BomLines
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM BomLines WHERE ItemNumber = BomLines.ManufacturedItemNumber
    ) AND ManufacturedItemNumber IS NOT NULL
)
, CTE AS (
    SELECT BomID, b.ManufacturedItemNumber, ManufacturedItemGroupID, Quantity, t.ParentItemFLag
    FROM BomLines b
    INNER JOIN TopLevelItems t ON t.ManufacturedItemNumber = b.ManufacturedItemNumber
)
SELECT ParentItemFLag, BomID, ManufacturedItemNumber, ManufacturedItemGroupID, Quantity
FROM CTE;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e8785a/1)

Comment: Thanks for responding, what does the "select 1" in the Anchor's Where clause mean?  I should clarify that 1 is a just a number, not a column name.  I was originally going to filter results to top level item (having a column with "1" in every row), union all that on to a filter that shows non-top level items (having a column with "0" in every row).  That way I would have a boolean column that I could easily use in an Anchor in a recursive CTE.  Also I just ran the query you posted and after 6 mins there is not a single row loaded.

Comment: The 1 is being used as a value for the ParentItemFlag column in the TopLevelItems subquery.  It's creating a boolean to identify whether an item is a top level item or not where 1 is true and 0 is false so that sounds like it may align with your goal.  Performance wise, that not exists is expensive and I'm guessing causing the bottleneck.  I tried rewriting it and updated the fiddle.  If you don't already have, would be good to make sure there is an index on ItemNumber and ManufacturedItemNumber